# What is the orbit of SDO (solar dynamics observatory)? How does it takes images of Sun non-stop?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, telescopes, satellites

There is a orbital diagram given in sdo website https://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/
It takes images of sun 24hr.

Answer (score 2):

The Solar Dynamics Observatory is in a non-equatorial geosynchronous orbit. The 28° inclination (initial inclination; currently it's 29.2°) means the spacecraft goes well north and south of the equator over the course of an orbit.

Even though the orbit has a significant inclination, it is low enough that the satellite always remains in view of its ground station in White Sands, New Mexico. This keeps costs low compared to requiring multiple ground stations, or compared to using expensive time on the Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System.

The Earth would eclipse the satellite's view of the Sun for several hours every day if the satellite was in a geostationary as opposed to geosynchronous orbit. The inclined orbit means that eclipses are instead limited an eclipse per day over the course of three week long windows ("eclipse seasons"); these windows occur every six months. The longest eclipses, which occur in the middle of those three week long windows, are only 72 minutes long.

Comment: sir can you please elaborate on the point that a inclined orbit reduces events when earth eclipse satellite's sun view.

Answer (score 0):

It's in a geosynchronous orbit about the Earth, so it remains approximately above a single point on Earth, although the orbit is not above the equator but rather offset by some amount.  It needs to be in such an orbit because it collects a *lot* of data and needs to be able to continually stream it down to Earth: I suppose they could have built multiple receivers but having one which the spacecraft can always see was a lot cheaper of course.

This means that the Earth does in fact occasionally eclipse the Sun from its perspective, although these eclipses could be pretty rare I think, depending on the relative timing of the orbit with the Earth's orbit about the Sun.

Comment: While it is in a geosynchronous orbit, it is not in a geostationary  orbit. This means it does **not** stay above a single point. The satellite's inclination is 28°, which means it goes from 28° north latitude to 28° south latitude, and back, over the course of an orbit.

Comment: @DavidHammen: that's why I said 'approximately'.  In particular: it remains in line of sight with its ground station.